# Truffle Console not working, opens truffle.js instead.

Tags: truffle, console

Am currently trying to learn Dapps, and trying to initiate Truffle. But, when I use the command "truffle console" in the Git CMD window, rather than opening the console, it opens up the 'truffle.js' file in my Adobe Brackets for editing. 
Not sure what to do here. 
Am attaching the images of the input and the output.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is coming from the fact that Windows 10 tries to execute the `truffle.js` instead of running `truffle.cmd`. It must have some kind of native JavaScript engine that I haven't found yet how to disable.

**Solution 1: Rename truffle.js to truffle-config.js**

According to [this article](https://truffle.readthedocs.io/en/beta/advanced/configuration/), the solution consist in renaming the file `truffle.js` to `truffle-config.js`.

**Solution 2: Change command name**

The solution consist in renaming `truffle` command to `truff` (for example) to avoid any confusion.
For that, just go to `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\npm` and rename 'truffle.cmd' to 'truff.cmd'.

Then you should be able to run `truff version`, `truff compile` and so on...

Comment: Hi Greg. Thanks so much. This seemed to have been the precise issue. 
I'd also been searching for the answer in the meantime, and got something similar from the https://truffle.readthedocs.io/en/beta/advanced/configuration/   which suggests the slightly different approach of changing the name of the .js file instead. 
Just noting it here for anybody who is facing this problem in the future. 
Thanks a lot again for taking out time and sharing your expertise which is so valuable for a beginner. Much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, yeah didn't know about this alternative. I'm updating the answer